# QGIS/OGR shp to tab export - crashing Mapinfo due to number format issues

Tags: qgis, gdal, convert, ogr, tab

I created a vector grid in QGIS and it exports as SHP -no issues. When I save as tab and try to open the file in MapInfo it crashes.

According to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mapinfo-l/sO-wcp9bnuQ this is due to MI only allowing  (20,16) for the decimal where QGIS had it as (23,15).

When I copied the data to a new (20,16) column and deleted the (23,15) column and then saved as tab, it worked fine in MI.

Is there some option to choose so that this would happen automatically in the save as tab process?

---

PROCESS - QGIS-Vector-Research Tools--Make Grid (I did 10000 ... 10km). Then save-as Tab. This file crashes MI.

Looking at the details of the tab I see it is 23,15 for one of the columns. If I create a copy with 20,16 and then save the tab, it works fine in MI.

---

So here is the shp file that won't work when it's converted by QGIS Save-as but works when converted in FME or Global. It is autogenerated using the QGIS steps mentioned above.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxjBqNsSHofKOFZJUVFiZGN0aHc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: AFAIK QGIS uses OGR to export to MapInfo TAB. So it is a GDAL/OGR question.

Comment: @Zoltan -thanks. I have added the tags for GDAL and OGR.

Comment: Could you add steps to reproduce the issue? It should be enough to describe how to make a similar grid.

Comment: A work around can be to save data to MIF/MID format and edit the MIF file to reduce the field size.

Comment: @Zoltan -cool but it's just adding a step, you can also edit the table in open office but really if a software is converting a file from one format to another it should automatically make sure the fields are correct for the new format. Globalmapper (shp-tab with shp having the wrong specs for direct conversion to tab) automatically outputs a compatible file..

Comment: MapInfo format is proprietary. Do you have any other reference about the field size limit of numeric attributes? I thing I could not find any from http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000300.shtml.

Comment: @user30184 -does this help? http://georezo.net/jparis/mb_r/doc/Tab_file_format/tab_file_format.htm --- I know that deleting the field with the wrong specs worked and also converting the shp to tab using FME (from MI) and using Globalmapper worked without any manual changes. I will add the offending shp shortly.

Comment: I could reproduce easily by saving the grid into MIF format where I can find attribute  COORD Decimal(24,15). The attribute is saved with the same precision also into shapefile which is OK and not offending at all. The only problem is that obviously there really is that (20,16) limit in the MapInfo format and the GDAL mitab driver does not know that. I found an official specification of MIF/MID http://resource.mapinfo.com/static/files/document/1074660800077/interchange_file.pdf. Unfortunately it does not mention the limits but only the format of a decimal column `decimal (width,decimals)`

Comment: @user30184 -thanks for the confirmation. Maybe we should elevate this to a bug in QGIS/GDAL/OGR ...